# Creating python virtualenv in jenkins with shiningpanda and requirements.txt

Tags: python, numpy, jenkins

I have some problems with jenkins and creating a virtualenv. I'm using the  shiningpanda plugin and the "Virtualenv Builder" build step combined with pyenv.

I can install packages with "pip install package" but I cannot install requirements from a requirements file, because the subsequent packages cannot find the installed packages, e.g. numexpr cannot find/import numpy.

Answer (score 2):

As I was typing my question, I found the answer to that problem: The current version (v0.21) of the shiningpanda plugin does NOT support pip's requirements.txt in virtualenv builders.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin

Comment: @surfer190 It did not fix the issue. The support for pip's installation by reading requirement.txt is still in their roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Current version (0.23) works in our setup like this (in Build-Virtualenv Builder, with Nature: Shell):

```
pushd %run_dir%
SET PYTHONPATH=%CD%
python -m pip install --upgrade -r configurations/requirements.txt
```

This has worked well even if libraries require each other.